# How to replace LightDM with GDM?

Tags: greeter

LightDM freezes to much on my Loki installation. After freeze I need to restart my computer hard. It is not good for my hard drive.

I want to try out the gdm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't try this out, but this should work:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/152256/how-do-i-switch-from-lightdm-to-gdm

(Note the comments down for Ubuntu >15.10)

Comment: tryied now gdm. I still experience freezes after wake up on my laptop T420.

Comment: sorry to hear this. Still it's the answer to your question. You could consider marking it as correct and open a new question (if you didn't find a solution already)